# Drupal theme Views template modifications

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I have implemented a simple View to output some data sourced from an api.

The issue is the Views table is included within a div with a class of table-responsive as shown below:

[image]

I attempted to locate the **div.table-responsive** markup by extending the display output template of my view but the markup in there does not account for that div.

Testing the following code:

```
<div class="view-content testing-content">
      <?php print $rows; ?>
</div>
<div>TESTING</div>
```

I found the **print $rows** statement is what's printing the not only the rows but the **div.table-responsive** within which they are contained.

**Can anyone advice how I can override the theme, from a module, so that in specific cases I can remove the table-responsive class of that div?**

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to override the top level Views template file for the specific View(s) you want to remove the class from.

In your View edit page go to Advanced -> Other -> Theme: Information 
Try the first template listed and note the suggested template files names for the specific View.

```
Display output: views-view.tpl.php
```

If doing this doesn't resolve the problem... are you using a Bootstrap theme? If so you may need to check the template.php file for a function that adds the "table-responsive" class as a wrapper around tables.